# Google Spreadsheet Formula- SUMIFS - of a column where numbers are between certain numeric values

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In google sheets im trying find the total sum of a column where numeric values are between a certain range e.g less than 11 and greater than or equal to one. Im using this formula but it errors:

```
=SUMIFS(B6:B,"<11",B6:B,">=1")

Error: SUMIFS expects all arguments after position 3 to be in pairs.
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct Syntax :

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])
```

`sum_range -` The range to be summed.

`criteria_range1 -` The range to check against criterion1.

`criterion1 -` The pattern or test to apply to criteria_range1.

`criteria_range2, criterion2, ... -` [ OPTIONAL ] - Additional ranges and criteria to check.

solution for you is you only putted the criteria for summing but not the range for summing
so lets say for example I want to SUM column A based on column B and C conditions (`B < 5` and `C >= 10` ):

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A6, B1:B6,"<5",B1:B6,"<5")
```

in order  to get the SUM of column B based  it's own conditions (`B < 5` and `C >= 10` ):

```
 =SUMIFS(B:B, B:B,"<5",B:B,">=10")
```

Comment: I only want to calculate values from a single column - B6:B. How would i do this?

Comment: @chappers i updated my answer please heck if it works

Comment: Nope. Its says Argument must be a range.

Comment: @chappers so sad can you please update your question and add example of your columns

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B6:B, B6:B*1<11, B6:B*1>=1))
```